# Project my query code performance to manager?

Tags: management, communication, performance-reviews

I worked on a project that brought the execution time of a query to 18 seconds from 5 minutes earlier. About 100 employees use this query to generate reports and further do their jobs. I am trying to find a way to project to my manager about the value gained by my efforts.
This is what I have in my mind:

> $saved=(4min42seconds) X (100 users) X (at least executed once a day) X
>   (21days or 1 month) X (employees cost to company an hour)

Should I just report how much more efficient the new query is, since I don't know how to translate the 4min42 seconds in terms of % more efficient, or should I use this formula to translate the efficiency gain?

Comment: "Made the query run 16x faster" sounds good IMHO.

Comment: This depends on what your boss is going to do with the information. Is this for your personal evaluation or does he have to present this to higher management? Why does everyone have to run the report independently? Can this run during off-hours and email everyone their report? You cut their time down to nearling zero.

Comment: Before you present anything to your boss, double-check your math. 5 minutes - 18 seconds is not 3:42. That said, keep it clean & simple - made the query 16X faster & reduced database resource utilization, allowing more people to use the system & execute their reports faster, with the same amount of hardware resources. If there's billing done per-CPU hour or other measures, mention that cost savings as well.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open, BUT with some conditions.  The scenario you gave is excellent as an example, BUT if we focus only on it, I believe the question becomes too localized.  If this question could be extended/edited to use the query situation as an example for a situation where one has made extreme improvements to an existing process, and would like to bring it up with their boss in a proper manner, I think this question would end up being extremely strong.

Comment: Also, as someone with a small amount of database experience, I would STRONGLY recommend double-checking that your changes result in a query 100% equivalent to the previous.  18 seconds from 5 minutes sounds a bit...too good to be true.

Comment: Six Sigma has quite a few methods of calculating the cost savings of a project.  It is not just the time you are saving people waiting for the results but how many more people will use the query now that they do not have to wait 5 minutes for it to run.

Comment: @acolyte: good idea to double check, but I've seen performance gains several magnitudes greater. It all depends on the skills of the developers in each end of the problem.

Comment: If my workplace computer needs to reboot to install updates for some 5min time, I typically do something else like grabbing a cup of coffe, check up on something with a coworker or make a phone call from my todo list. It's likely safe to assume similar behaviour for your users. Of course, there is a slight gain in decreased context switching but you can hardly prove it in $.

Comment: @acolyte, I have brought things down from hours to seconds in db performance tuning. 5 minutes to 18 seconds is entirely believable.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comments. was too saturated to check the math while posting. anyways. I agree with, and also account the fact that people won't just sit idle staring at their screens! They will multitask. I am also compromising on other numbers like approximating 100 users instead of the 175 actual licensed users (these costs like >3k each so only the ones who really needs em gets em). But yes, decreased performance because of context switching and the times when users are awaiting the results because their next task/calculations depend on these results are also the case I thought.

Comment: Hi camelbrush, I removed the last edits you made, since they seemed more like comments than something that was actually part of the question. Also, let's stay focused on an answerable question, not "suggestions" or "advice". These two keywords oftentimes result in people thinking a post is not constructive or a poll, which can lead to it's closure.  Hope this helps!

Comment: @jmort253
Thanks. for the edit and the explanation.

Comment: A'ight, i think this question is too localized.  I'll put some time aside during lunch to try and tweak it a bit.

Comment: Isnt a developers responsibility to make code better ? I guess this is the reason most developers are hired.

Comment: I am a project manager, with dbs background. And the query responds to a team brewed system, not by our IT/IS team. So, as long as others had the data (from the query), that all my job expecation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, In the spirit of the comment thread, I'm going to stay out of the details here:

**Reporting on Cool Things You've Done to Management:**

1. **Know when a metric will help you** - doing a quick verbal status report probably doesn't need a heavy metric.  Just saying "I brought our slow query from 5 minutes to 15 seconds" is pretty cool, and a good technical manager will get that.  Especially if this was a few days of effort, don't go crazy.
2. **Report big stuff in a big way (understand impact/work scope)** - if this was a many week effort, or something with a high degree of complexity, take more time to figure out how to be clear about your impact.  Putting a spin on success takes time, so only do this with the time you'll take highlighting the work is less than the work itself.
3. **Know what numbers the bosses like (understand audience scope)** - for example

   - A technical manager who's fixed queries himself is likely to be happy with hearing the query that was 5 minutes is now 15 seconds - everyone was complaining about that query, and he knows that this is a great thing.
   - A project manager cares about team efficiency - a number more like "I saved the team X hours of time waiting for the query a month" is likely to help.  Also - for  a reasonably technical project manager or big picture person, being able to highlight extensions of this success are helpful - for example, in a software project - speeding up a build process moves the capabilities of your team from nightly builds to build before check-in - which means a whole new and more efficient method of developing code.  That's not just the time for a query, it's the time saved from all sorts of check-in errors and bug fixing.
   - For contract work, the bosses and customers may care about $ saved.  If development costs were X dollars/hour, and now you've saved N hours, you've saved X * N dollars.  Not something to make up on your own - check in with your direct management to see what cost estimates you can get.
4. **Show any basis for estimate** - to do a calculation, you'll end up making some assumptions - the length of the query you know - but how are you figuring out how often people use it?  Is that really everyone, or just the a sub-group of users?  Justify your estimates and clarify where you've had to make some.
5. **Check before sharing** - always check in with management before quoting metrics to external parties.  The farther you are sharing, the more you should check in.  Telling another team in the same company is far less of an issue than telling customers or competitors, for example.

Comment: A very good answer covering everything I needed.
My manager just moved in the position from the Chemical Dept.! I just joined in as program manager with dbs bg. He might not care too much about execution time, as for him, others were anyways performing according to their job expectations.
So, taking your advice, I think it be good to convey the metric in time terms, both for query execution and my efforts! be casual and yet informative.

P.S:Read your profile! would marry you if I could. ;)

Comment: Glad it helps. :)

Answer (score 4):

It depends on how you report your efforts. Will you be doing a presentation, formal report, email etc...

If you are reporting it at a high level such as email or powerpoint to higher ups then just display the range of possible savings in whatever unit you desire-- savings per day, week, year...

If you are reporting it as detailed report with technical information then include more about how you derived this savings continuum.

How to guessimate your savings range...

I simplified your formula...

```
WageSavingsPerDay = AvergaeWageRatePerAction * Executions
```

Now guess low estimates for hourly wages and how many times you think the query will be executed.

> Example Low End: $15/hr, 100 times a day (executions)

```
AverageWageRatePerAction = $15 * .0583(% of an hour the new query time saves) = .875
```

therefore the low end would be...

```
WageSavingsPerDay = .875 * 100 = $87.50
```

Now repeat for the high end...

> Example High End: $25/hr, 165 times a day (executions)

```
AverageWageRatePerAction = $25 * .0583(% of an hour the new query time saves) = 1.46
```

Therefore the high end would be...

```
WageSavingsPerDay = 1.46 * 165 = $240.60
```

By reducing the query time of x task I have saved the company between $87.50-$240 in wages per day depending on query frequency and wagerates.

*Obviously the better information you have regarding wages and query frequency will improve the accuracy of your calculation. This also assumes that people are not productive during the previous duration of the query.*

*Additionally it should be noted that wages saved may not be the only manner in which a firm would save money.*

*For example: Reduced query time also reduces CPU usage which also could lower power consumption...etc*

Comment: +1 for the well stated answer and the low-high range considerations. That would be a good way and also more casual way to communicate the efforts. 
Thanks